# Determine whether Dropbox or Facebook SDKs should handle an application delegate call

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have to integrate the latest FB-SDK into my iOS app - and the nightmare starts with the app delegate.

The docs say to implement this in the app delegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:launchOptions];
}

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {
  return [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application
    openURL:url
    sourceApplication:sourceApplication
    annotation:annotation
  ];
}
```

But my app isn't for FB only, it does Dropbox and YouTube uploads as well.

So my `application:openURL:` method looks like this now:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setIdleTimerDisabled:YES];

    // Facebook

    if([FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url]){
        BOOL result = [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url];
        return result;
    }

    // Dropbox

    if ([[DBSession sharedSession] handleOpenURL:url]) {
        if ([[DBSession sharedSession] isLinked]) {
            NSLog(@"App linked successfully!");

        }
        return YES;
    }
    // Add whatever other url handling code your app requires here
    return NO;
}
```

`FBSession` doesn't exist anmyore, though. So how do I tell the `openURL:` calls from Facebook and Dropbox apart?

Comment: Not sure but you can maybe try: BOOL facebookCanHandle = [[FBSDKApplicationDelegate sharedInstance] application:application openURL:url sourceApplication:sourceApplication annotation:annotation];

if (!facebookCanHandle) {
 // try Dropbox
}